# Linear regression getting worse results on training set with additional parameters

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear

I'm running Linear Regression on a synthetic data set based on two features - $x_1$,$x_2$. The target value is $x_2 + x_1^2 + x_1x_2$

Running linear regression (over Spark with L-BFGS) with just the right features produces a very good result over the training set - (coeffs and intercept are the results returned by the algorithm)

The features are $(x_1,x_2,x_1^2,x_2^2,x_1x_2)$

```
coeffs: List(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0) intercept 0.000039508668123 error: 0.0000286960471777 lambda: 0.0
```

However, whenever I add **additional** features, somehow the result gets worse!
Note that the new features aren't even used at all - they all get 0.

The features are $(x_1,x_2,x_1^2,x_2^2,x_1x_2,x_1^3,x_2^3,x_1^2x_2,x_2^2x_1)$

```
coeffs: List(0.07, 2.02, 1.0, -0.01, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) intercept -23.02563372048826 error: 5.03134487460479 lambda: 0.0
```

Note that lambda is 0 so no regularization is utilized.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: What is the length of your feature vectors? i.e. what is the size of the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how you solve the linear regression, but if it uses gradient descent then it will take more iterations to get to the same score (more parameters to optimize = slower optimization)

Answer (score 0):

Adding more details may help others to answer your question. With current information here are my guess:

- One possible problem is you do not have sufficient data to run the third order polynomial expansion.
- Another possible problem is the ground truth is $x_2+x_1^2+x_1x_2$, so the ground truth coefficients for other terms are zero.